# JQuery: Animation/Traversing DOM tree

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-animate

Overview:

I'm working on a Q&A page for a website.  All the answers are initially hidden.  I'm trying to animate the answers sliding out.  There are little pictures of Q and A next to the questions and answers, respectively.

I want to move the Q to the left, have the answer slide down, and the "A" picture to fade in on first click of the question.

On the second click of the same question, I want it to hide.  If another one is clicked, hide all and display the answer.

Code:

I can't get the code to work properly.  I'm assuming there is something wrong with my DOM tree navigation but I'm not sure what.

HTML:

```
        <div class="faq">
            <div class="faq-question">Question goes here </div>
            <div class="faq-answer-container">
                <div class="faq-answer">Answer goes here </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

This is one question/answer combo.  There are five total on the page and they all use the same classes as the one shown (they all look exactly the same except for message content).

JQuery:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){



            $(".faq-question").toggle(function(){

                <!-- this slides up all siblings -->

                $(this).siblings().slideUp();

                <!-- animation -->

                $(this).find('.letter-q').animate({left:"-=15"},"slow", function() {
                $(this).closest('faq').find('faq-answer-container').slideDown('slow');
                $(".letter-a").fadeIn("slow");
                });

            },function() {

            <!-- slides up all siblings -->
                $(this).siblings().slideUp();

                <!-- animation -->

                $('.letter-q').animate({left:"+=15"},"slow", function() {
                $(this).closest('faq').find('faq-answer-container').slideUp('slow');
                $(".letter-a").fadeOut("slow");

            });             
        });
        });
    </script>
```

.letter-q and .letter-a are the classes designated to the pictures.  For some reason, on first click, the Q fades out and on second and all subsequent clicks, all the other Q's start shifting to the right.  The answer never slides down.  I'm fairly new to JQuery but I've read the API material on everything I used.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your first problem is using HTML comments inside javascript. You need to comment using `//` (singleline) or `/* */` (multiline). Next, try setting up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem and make it easier for us to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the situation, but I came up with what I took away from the question. Let me know how far off I am and any questions and I can go into detail.

Also, if you can post a jsFiddle of what you're currently working with, that would help as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.faq-question-container').click(function() {
        //-- move all instances of .faq-answer-container up
        $('.faq-answer-container').slideUp();

        //-- move 'active' instances back to their original position and remove 'active' class
        $('.faq-question-active').removeClass('faq-question-active').animate({
            left: '-=50'
        });

        //-- slide/animate our question
        $(this).find('.faq-answer-container').slideToggle();
        $(this).addClass('faq-question-active').animate({
            left: '+=50'
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qzvN/4/

Those comments should also be replaced with the proper syntax. Those are PHP comments you are using.

Replace

```
<!-- PHP Comment -->
```

with

```
// Javascript comment
```

or

```
/*
   Group of JS comments
*/
```

Comment: Got it to work!  As far as the comments go, that's how notepad++ comments out JQuery for some reason.  It hasn't given me problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEywH/

If anyone is curious:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".faq").each(function(){

                <!-- this is to add the images to the questions and answers -->

                    $(this).prepend('<img src="images/faq-q.png" alt="Question" class="letter-q">');
                    $(this).closest(".faq").find(".faq-answer").prepend('<img src="images/faq-a.png" alt="Answer" class="letter-a">');
                }); 



                $(".faq-question").toggle(function(){

                    <!-- this initializes the state -->

                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find(".faq-answer-container").slideUp();
                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find(".letter-a").fadeOut();
                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find('.letter-q').animate({left:"25px"},"fast");

                    <!-- animation -->

                    $(this).closest(".faq").find('.letter-q').animate({left:"-=15px"},"slow");
                    $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq-answer-container').slideDown('slow');
                    $(this).closest(".faq").find(".letter-a").fadeIn("slow");

                },function() {

                <!-- initialization -->
                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find(".faq-answer-container").slideUp();
                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find(".letter-a").fadeOut();
                    $(this).closest(".faq").siblings(".faq").find('.letter-q').animate({left:"25px"},"fast");

                    <!-- animation -->

                    $(this).closest(".faq").find('.letter-q').animate({left:"25px"},"slow", function() {
                        $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq-answer-container').slideUp('slow');
                        $(this).closest('.faq').find(".letter-a").fadeOut("slow");
                    });
                });             
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="faq-container">
            <img src="images/faq-header.jpg" alt="faq header">
            <div class="faq">
                <div class="faq-question">How much is the application fee? Can I request an application fee waiver? </div>
                <div class="faq-answer-container">
                    <div class="faq-answer">The application fee is $70 and we do not offer fee waivers at this time. </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
```

It turns out that my DOM traversing was pretty bad.  A little research and I was able to figure out my issues.